# Внешние и внутренние бибилотеки python

Tags: python

Не смог найти конкретного объяснения, что в **python** является внутренней библиотекой, а что внешней. Например модули `math` или `re` они какие?
Является ли все что идёт через `import` внешней библиотекой?...

Comment: имхо все библиотеки внешние.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, абсолютно нет. Через `import` вы подключаете все возможные библиотеки, модули и все остальное.

Я бы разделил на три категории все, что подключается через `import`

1. Модули, которые поставляются вместе с python. К ним относятся такие модули как `datetime`, `collections` и еще великое множество. Весь список можно найти [в документации](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html). [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#module-math) и [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) относятся именно к таким.
2. Модули поставляемые третьей стороной. Популярные примеры `requests`, `django`. Как правило они устанавливаются с помощью менеджера пакетов - `pip`, `conda`. Пример где их можно найти [здесь](https://pypi.org/). Но так же могут распротаняться и в виде бинарников.
3. Самописные модули. Это то, что вы реализуете у себя в проекте.

Для подключения и использования в своем проекте, для всех описанных случаев вам необходимо использовать `import`, как ключевое слово.

Внутренняя и внешняя библиотека. Эти понятия мной не используются и если встречается такое в литературе, то надо в этой литературе и смотреть пояснения. Это все на уровне терминов.

Comment: built-in обычно называют то, что встроено (built-in) в сам язык, например стандартные типы и функции - int, float, list, input, и т.д. То что вообще не нужно никак импортировать, и оно всегда под рукой. Модули datetime, random, math - это уже не встроенное, а поставляемое вместе с Python, стандартные модули или "батарейки". Они не встроены в язык, это просто часть стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @insolor согласен исправлю